# Use one mod_auth_openidc in Apache for two applications

Tags: apache, web-applications

I currently have an app running on apache and using the mod_auth_openidc. I now want to add a second application under a different URL. I assume I need to add a second "Location" to my httpd.conf e.g:

```
<Location /application_ONE.html>
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user
</Location>

#new application 

<Location /application_TWO.html>
  AuthType openid-connect
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

How can I add a second "OIDCRedirectURI" to the mod_auth_openid? Is it possible to do this?

I have been looking online but can seem to find anything. I may have found a source saying that it was not possible but wanted to confirm.

Comment: there's no need to add a 2nd OIDCRedirectURI, things will just work with your config as it is now